# how to use in operator in dynamo db

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a user table with a field username. I need to write something equivalent to this in dynamo db: Select * from user where username in('a','b','c');

Adding more from code prosepective i have usernames in an array say var arr=['a','b','c'];

I so far tried this which is giving me zero result

```
    this.dynamo.client.scanAsync({
        TableName: this.dynamo.table('users'),
        FilterExpression: 'username IN (:list)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':list': arr.toString()
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return {
            userFriends: result.Item.friends
        };
    });
```

When I pass one element in array it give me result searching passed single element in user table but its not working with more than one element in array.

Answer (score 20):

The individual users should be given as comma separated String variables. JavaScript array is equivalent to List in AWS DynamoDB data type. The DynamoDB can't compare the String data type in database with List attribute (i.e. Array in JavaScript).

```
var params = {
    TableName : "Users",
    FilterExpression : "username IN (:user1, :user2)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ":user1" : "john",
        ":user2" : "mike"
    }
};
```

**Construct the object from array for FilterExpression:-**

Please refer the below code for forming the object dynamically based on Array value.

```
var titleValues = ["The Big New Movie 2012", "The Big New Movie"];
var titleObject = {};
var index = 0;
titleValues.forEach(function(value) {
    index++;
    var titleKey = ":titlevalue"+index;
    titleObject[titleKey.toString()] = value;
});

var params = {
    TableName : "Movies",
    FilterExpression : "title IN ("+Object.keys(titleObject).toString()+ ")",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : titleObject
};
```

**Note:-**

I don't think IN clause with 1000s of usernames is a good idea in terms of performance.

Comment: say i have 1000 elements in username array so do i have to write in 1000 times ?

Comment: I have updated the answer to dynamically form the filterexpression and expressionattributevalues. Take a look at it.

Comment: thanks good example. Please can you give me example for pagination or limit with the query ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074919/dynamo-db-pagination?noredirect=1#comment98788697_56074919

Comment: The dynamodb documentation states: The list can contain up to 100 values. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html

Answer (score 0):

I made some improvements in @notionquest answer

```js
var searchKey = "title";
var searchPossibleValues = ["The Big New Movie 2012", "The Big New Movie"];

var titleObject = searchPossibleValues.reduce((state, term, idx) => {
  state[":titlevalue" + idx] = term;
  return state;
}, {});

var params = {
  TableName: "Movies",
  FilterExpression: `${searchKey} IN (${Object.keys(titleObject).toString()})`,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: titleObject,
};
```

It's a little bit more useful