# How to use “IN” statement in FilterExpression using array - dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Checked AWS document but did not find any working example.

Here is my attempt

```
var params = {
            TableName: "User",
            IndexName:"a-b-index",
            KeyConditionExpression: "Country = :country and #s = :status",
            FilterExpression: "Id IN (:e)",
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":country ": "USA",
              ":status": 1,
              ":e": "1"

            },
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#s": "Status"}
          };

          //get users
          dynamodb.query(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err)
              //error
            else {
              //success

            }
          });
```

Got records but it is fetching record which have id `1` but i want to use array like this

```
 var params = {
        TableName: "User",
        IndexName:"a-b-index",
        KeyConditionExpression: "Country = :country and #s = :status",
        FilterExpression: "Id IN (:e)",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":country ": "USA",
          ":status": 1,
          ":e": ["1","2","3"]

        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#s": "Status"}
      };

      //get users
      dynamodb.query(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err)
          //error
        else {
          //success

        }
       });
```

How can make above code as working.want to get records. syntax is correct and query run without error but i am not getting records

Comment: How did you test it?

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi what do you mean ?

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi i am using serverless framework.checking locally

Comment: is it working on dynamodb local host?

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi i am not using dynamodb in localhost.i am using live dynamodb

Comment: try to use dynamo db in local host http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html when dynamodb with serverless try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dynamodb-local it is easiest for offline development

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi ok but i don't think it will solve my issue

Comment: What is your error massage

Comment: @NiroshanRanapathi syntax is correct but i am not getting records

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222158/how-to-use-in-operator-in-dynamo-db/40228197#40228197)

**Summary:-**

**For fixed number of values in "IN" clause:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName : "Users",
    FilterExpression : "username IN (:user1, :user2)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ":user1" : "john",
        ":user2" : "mike"
    }
};
```

**For more elements in array and forming the FilterExpression dynamically:-**

```
var titleValues = ["The Big New Movie 2012", "The Big New Movie"];
var titleObject = {};
var index = 0;
titleValues.forEach(function(value) {
    index++;
    var titleKey = ":titlevalue"+index;
    titleObject[titleKey.toString()] = value;
});

var params = {
    TableName : "Movies",
    FilterExpression : "title IN ("+Object.keys(titleObject).toString()+ ")",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : titleObject
};
```

Comment: thanks for answer,will try it,dynamodb does not support join and i want to fetch records based on other table records so i want to use in operator because there is no any other option but you are telling that it is not good for 1000 user in terms of performance than which is best approach ?

Comment: In that case, you need to export or stream it to EMR or something and retrieve the required information. Most of the NOSQL databases doesn't support join. Other option is to review the data model to store all required data in one table if the size is less than 4KB. Please note that most of the answers in SO are not written specifically for the requirement. Sometimes they are just pointers to resolve the problem.

Comment: This is not correct:"KeyConditions" or "KeyConditionExpression" is required field

Comment: Thank you its working. Only missing -> titleObject[titleKey.toString()] = {S: value}

Comment: No need to keep an index variable, the second param in the forEach callback is the index of the current value: `titleValues.foreach(function (value, index) { ...`

Comment: `KeyConditions` or `KeyConditionExpression` is required for `query` but not for `scan`.

Comment: "ValidationException: Invalid FilterExpression: Expression size has exceeded the maximum allowed size; expression size: 6324" :-(

Answer (score 8):

[notionquest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6337748/notionquest)'s answer is correct but i cant use my other values in `ExpressionAttributeValues` like `:country` and `:status` so here is modified answer to make it working as per my requirements

```
var AttributeValuesObject = {};

  AttributeValuesObject[':country '] = "USA";
  AttributeValuesObject[':status'] = 1;

  var titleValues = ["1", "2"];
  var titleObject = {}; 

  var index = 0; 

  titleValues.forEach(function(value) {
    index++;
    var titleKey = ":titleValue"+index;
    AttributeValuesObject[titleKey.toString()] = value;
    titleObject[titleKey.toString()] = value;
  });

  var params = {
    TableName: "User",
    IndexName:"a-b-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "Country = :country and #s = :status",
    FilterExpression: "Id IN ("+Object.keys(titleObject).toString()+ ")",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: AttributeValuesObject,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {"#s": "Status"}
  };

  //get users
  dynamodb.query(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err)
      //error
    else {
      //success

    }
   });
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if the concept was helpful though it was not written specifically for your use case?

Answer (score 8):

I've done it like this, parsing the params list once

```js
const users = [{userId:1, name:'joe'}, {userId:2, name:'mike'}]
const expressionAttributeValues = {};
const userIdParams = users.map((u, i) => {
  const userParam = `:user${i}`;
  expressionAttributeValues[userParam] = u.userId;
  return userParam;
}).join(',')
var params = {
    TableName : 'Users',
    FilterExpression : `username IN (${userIdParams})`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues : expressionAttributeValues
};
```

Answer (score 5):

The Python3 version:

```py
def get_filter_for_in_clause(column_name, in_values, column_type="S"):
    expressions = []
    for i in range(len(in_values)):
        expressions.append(f':temp{i}')
    filter_expression = f'{column_name} IN ({", ".join(expressions)})'

    expression_attribute_values = {}
    for index, expression in enumerate(expressions):
        expression_attribute_values[expression] = {column_type: in_values[index]}

    return filter_expression, expression_attribute_values
```

Usage:

```py
column = 'testcolumn'
inputs = ['testvalue1', 'testvalue2', 'testvalue3']
filter_expression, expression_attribute_values = get_filter_for_in_clause(column, inputs)
```

Result:

```py
# filter_expression = 'testcolumn IN (:temp0, :temp1, :temp2)'
# expression_attribute_values = {':temp0': {'S': 'testvalue1'}, ':temp1': {'S': 'testvalue2'}, ':temp2': {'S': 'testvalue3'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use notionquest's approach and simply insert your other attribute values inside the `titleObject{}`.
e.g.

```
var titleObject = { ": country": "USA", ":status": 1, };
```

> Note: You might have to add schema like "S" if you're not using
>   DocumentClient

```
     var titleObject = { 
      ":country": { "S":"USA" }, ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using es5 and map:

```js
const params = {
  TableName: 'personalizations',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'accountId = :accountId',
  FilterExpression: `websiteId IN (${websites.map(w => `:${w.websiteId}`).join(',')})`,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {':accountId': accountId}
}
for (const website of websites) {
  params.ExpressionAttributeValues[`:${website.websiteId}`] = website.websiteId
}

const {Items: personalizations} = await docClient.query(params).promise()
```

Comment: Potential issue here if you had duplicate websiteId's (would cause dup keys). @kords answer avoids this by using .map index for key names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want filter a column by a given array using `IN` with DynamodbV3 and TypeScript you  can do this:

```
  const idsArray = ['1206133642', '1315193154', etc....]
  const filterExpressions: string[] = [];
  const ExpressionAttributeValues: Record<string, string> = {};

  idsArray.forEach((data, index) => {
    filterExpressions.push(`:id${index}`);
    ExpressionAttributeValues[`:id${index}`] = data;
  });

  const FilterExpression = `tableId = :TableId AND id IN (${filterExpressions.map(
    (data) => data
  )})`;

  const result = await dynamodbDocumentClient.send(
    new ScanCommand({
      TableName: this.tableName,
      FilterExpression,
      ExpressionAttributeValues,
    })
  );
```

This query retrieves all items in my transaction table that match with a given array of ids (in mycase isArray)