# DynamoDb IN operator in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a working DynamoDb query, but I'm trying to add an IN operator and can't figure out the syntax for the FilterExpression.

`pages` is a List<Integer> and I have an attribute in my table which is an Integer, so I'm doing something like this

```
attrValues.put(":pages", AttributeValue.fromL(pages.stream()
                     .map(i->AttributeValue.fromN(i.toString()))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList())));

String filterExpression = "in(originalPageNumber, :pages)"

final QueryRequest.Builder queryBuilder = QueryRequest.builder()
                .tableName(Parameters.addPrefix(TABLE_NAME))
                .keyConditionExpression(keyConditionExpression)
                .expressionAttributeNames(attrNameAlias)
                .expressionAttributeValues(attrValues)
                .filterExpression(filterExpression);
```

(this is not the complete code.  Just the relevant parts)

But it doesn't like my syntax at all.  I've tried `originalPageNumber in :pages` and other variations as well.

## Update

Other things I tried

Tried setting `:pages` to

```
final String pagesStr = pages.stream().map(i -> i.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "(", ")"));
final AttributeValue pagesAttr = AttributeValue.fromS(pagesStr);
attrValues.put(":pages", pagesAttr);
```

or `AttributeValue(S=(1, 2))`

I then got rid of `:pages` altogether and just set filterExpression to `in(originalPageNumber, (1, 2))`.  Still no luck.
Also tried `originalPageNumber in (1, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
String filterExpression = "originalPageNumber IN (:pages)"
```

`:pages` would need to be a comma separated list of values. Which should essentially map to:

```
String filterExpression = "originalPageNumber IN (1,2,3,7,9)"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Are you saying that  :pages should be a literal string, and not an attributeValue object?

Comment: A literal string could possibly work, but I'm thinking more along the lines of parsing the values in the list to individual expressionAttributeValues like you can see in this JS example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40294674/7909676

Comment: Tried your suggestions and still no luck.  I updated my question with this additional information