# Query Dynamodb for multiple strings in a single field

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query for two different values from the same field or column. In this instance I would like to retrieve rows where the fulfilled item are true or false. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
const params = {
            TableName: "Orders",
            IndexName: 'fulfilled-shippingId-index',

            KeyConditionExpression: "fulfilled = :fulfilled",
           //FilterExpression : 'contains(fulfilled=true) OR fulfilled=false',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ":fulfilled": "true",
              ":fulfilled": "false"
            }
```

let me know if this isn't possible or if there would be a different way to do this through a loop or maybe just multiple requests from the application? As of now it just returns the last Expression Attribute Value.

thanks!

Comment: Hmm can you not use "IN" within a FilterExpression, I'm afk at the moment I'll update in a bit?

Comment: Thank you, Mrk, it seems there is an IN within filter expression but It doesnt seem to be working for me either. FilterExpression : "fulfilled IN (:false, :true)",

   ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":false": "false",
    ":true": "true"
  },

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use in operator in dynamo db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222158/how-to-use-in-operator-in-dynamo-db)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible.

> **KeyConditionExpression**
>
> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key
>   value.

You must specify a *single* partition key value.

Using a `FilterExpression` here won't help since FilterExpressions are applied after the data is read. Also, a FilterExpression cannot contain partition key or sort key attributes.

Since `fulfilled = true OR fulfilled = false` is a tautology, I would recommend just using [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) to read all of the items in your `fulfilled-shippingId-index`