# DynamoDB Java SDK query to match items in a list

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying  to use SQL IN clause kind of feature in dynamoDB. I tried using `withFilterExpression` but I'm not sure how to do it. I looked at similar questions as they were too old. Is there a better method to do this? This is the segment of code I have got. I have used a static List as example but it is actually dynamic.

```
def getQuestionItems(conceptCode : String) = {

  val qIds = List("1","2","3")

  val querySpec = new QuerySpec()
  .withKeyConditionExpression("concept_id = :c_id")
  .withFilterExpression("question_id in :qIds") // obviously wrong
  .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
    .withString(":c_id", conceptCode));
 questionsTable.query(querySpec);
}
```

I need to pass qID list to fetch results similar to IN clause in SQL Query.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222158/how-to-use-in-operator-in-dynamo-db/40228197#40228197). Basically you need to form key list/value list dynamically

```java
.withFilterExpression("question_id in (:qId1, :qId2, ... , :qIdN)")
.withValueMap(new ValueMap()
    .withString(":qId1", ..) // just do this for each element in the list in a loop programmatically
    ....
    .withString(":qIdN", ..)
);
```

Mind there is a restriction on maxItems in 'IN'